# Not the right <type>?

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, wcf-data-services

I'm confused. I've got a Silverlight project that currently runs and displays a list of servers from my mocked model (I am following the MVVM pattern).

The interface is coded as follows:

```
public class GetServersCompletedEventArgs : EventArgs 
{
    public Exception Error {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<LicenseServer> Results {get; private set;}

    public GetServersCompletedEventArgs(Exception error, IEnumerable<LicenseServer> results)
    {
        this.Error = error;
        this.Results = results;
    }
}

public delegate void GetServersCompletedEvent(GetServersCompletedEventArgs e);

public interface IDataService
{
    void GetServers();

    event GetServersCompletedEvent GetServersCompleted;
}
```

As you can see the CompletedEventArgs return the results as a IEnumerable.

The problem that I am having is defining `<LicenseServer>` in such a way that I can stub it with fake data or populate the results from real data (ala ado.net data services).

I've created a local class LicenseServer but the service always returns a different type of LicenseServer.

I get an error:

> convert Unable to cast object of type 
>   'DataServiceOrderedQuery[LicenseMon.LMonServiceReference.License_Server]'
>   to type
>   'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1[LicenseMon.Model.LicenseServer]

Which I read as  LicenseServer from the service reference cannot be converted over to the LicenseServer I've defined in my model class

Why am I having trouble? Shouldn't I be able to develop my classes independently and be able to switch between a live database and my internally generated data? Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Any code samples, explanations, links etc would be most helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often, when consuming a web resource (SOAP, WCF or ADO.NET Data Services), a *separate* client proxy class is generated. This will have similar layout, but has no automatic conversion to your local type. Some systems support type re-use (WCF etc), but not all.

You could add a conversion or an interface to the partial class; but in general, you should treat this as a separate type.